# C# Searchable, Positionable PictureBox

Tags: c#, search, position, picturebox

I've been searching about this for a while and haven't found what I'm looking for.

I want to be able to have an image in a picturebox that can be positioned to a point by means of a "search box". Basically, mapping locations in pixels to certain phrases or letters that then shift the position on the picturebox.

I tried to set the location using points, however this does not change the picture at all; the location after calculating the code below stubbornly stays at (3,3).

The picture also is large (~3500 x ~3000) and needs scrolls bars to fully view it.

Here's my code

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (textBox1.Text == "m")
          {
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\User\Desktop\map.jpg");
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(700, 200);
            // ^ The location does not change and stays at (3,3)
            //  The picturebox is not set as locked
          }
```

Do I need to do something different? Or is the issue with my picture for not allowing me to change the location?

**EDIT** I found the Solution thanks to the help below. I had to use a panel and place the picturebox within. Below is the code I used.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1.AutoScroll = true;
        panel1.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Desktop\image.jpg");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        label1.Visible = true;
        int Hvalue = panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value;
        label1.Text = Hvalue.ToString();

        label2.Visible = true;
        int Vvalue = panel1.VerticalScroll.Value;
        label2.Text = Vvalue.ToString();

        if (textBox1.Text == "m")
        {
            // these are just values that I put in
            panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = 616;
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = 90;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can move the [scrollbar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.value.aspx) instead

Comment: @Martheen Really? I looked that up too but could find anything. Maybe I was searching incorrectly.

Comment: Add "msdn" when googling for .NET built in class documentation

Comment: One way is to place the picturebox inside an autoscroll panel and then move it.. of course you still need to know which points you want.

Comment: I got it figured out! Thank you guys for your help. I'll post the code sample as a different comment